# Python Prime Number

Tags: python, debugging, primes

I just started learning python. I'm trying to write a program that prints prime no. but it also printing no. ending with 5.

```
n = 2

while n >= 2:
    if n == 2:
        print(n)
        n += 1

    while n >= 3:
        if n == 3:
            print(n)
            n += 2
        for i in range (3,n):

            if n % i != 0:
                print(n)
                n += 2
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger to step through your code to see what it is doing. For example, look at what happens when n is 25. You will see it printed because it is not divisible by 3. You need to rethink your algorithm for deciding if a number is prime.

Comment: also, add your python's version tag(`python-3.x`,`python-2.7`) please.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algorithm for deciding primes:

```
def prime(iterations):
    primes = [2]
    x = math.floor(math.sqrt(iterations)) + 1
    for i in range(iterations):
        if i > 2:
            primes.append(i)
    for i in range(x):
        if i > 1:
            j=2
            while i*j <= iterations:
                if i*j in primes:
                    primes.remove(i*j)
                j += 1
    print(primes)
```

explanations:

line 4: appends every num to primes

line 7 and line 3: finds numbers between 1 and iterations and removes all possible factors

line 13: cycling through factors

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for finding prime number.

```
num = int(input("Enter number: "))
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num, " is not a prime number")
            break
    else:
        print(num, " is a prime number")
else:
    print(num, " is not a prime number")
```

prime number always greater than 1 so you have check for it also.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=int(input("Give your No: "))

for k in range(2,x):
    if ((x%k)==0):
        print('Not prime no')
        break
else:
    print("Prime no")
```